# webview loadDataWithBaseUrl not loading page with formatting

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an html page that I receive dynamically in which I replace the body with my own text. I then pass it to a webview using loadDataWithBaseUrl which shows my replaced text but there is formatting.

The entire idea is to get the page with css and js from the server and I only inject the correct text into the body at location 'X' (there is a token string that i'm replacing). Unfortunately the webview is showing the page without any css or other formatting whatsoever:

this is how I load the webview with the text which is a full html & js

```
mContenetWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Please any help will do since I dont know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I believe the issue is that the css and js files are referenced in the html file as absolute file paths. Therefore when you download the web content html and inject your own text into it, your file is now trying to reference the local css and js files which do not exist. Try downloading the css and js files with the base html file?

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS, JS, and such are referenced via relative paths, replace `null` in your `loadDataWithBaseURL()` call with the actual URL you loaded the HTML from. Otherwise, `WebView` has no way to resolve those relative paths.

Comment: I dont think this is the case - my problem is that it removes "new line" spacing and shows one long string instead of a string with correct spacing and paragraphs